# Magento: Is it possible to set different price for different customers?

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I will describe issue.

I have different customers. It could be retailer or wholesaler or usual customer.

For each type exists own product price:

customer - 120
retailer - 100
wholesaler - 90

If wholesaler or retailer is loginned in then he can see own price: 90 and 100 respectively.
If it is usual custormer (unregistered user) then he can see customer price - 120.

So how to make magento to show different price in this case?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to achieve this using customer groups, tier prices, a second store front for B2B customers and so on.

A lot depends on how you will be updating the prices, what you want is a manageable system that can be integrated to a 3rd party system, plain spreadsheets or easily updateable in the Magento backend.

With a second store front you will need some extensions to make it login only with some friendly means for trade customers to apply for an account.